# Already declared variable cannot resolve

Tags: java, validation, variables

double width cannot be resolved along with int walls even though before I started my Surface Area calculations, it compiled.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_3_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Customer Name

    System.out.println("Enter your First Name");
    String Firstn = in.next();
    System.out.println("Enter your Last Name");
    String Lastn = in.next();
    System.out.println("Valued Customer Name: " + Firstn + " " + Lastn);

    //Wall Measurements

    System.out.println("Enter the Width");
    if(in.hasNextDouble()){
        double width = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Width/Height: " + width);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter only numbers");
    }
    System.out.println("Enter number of walls");
    if(in.hasNextInt()){
        int walls = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Walls: " + walls);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter only integers");
    }
    //Calculate Surface Area - Width Height and Length are all the same measurement
    double SA = ((width * width) * walls);
    System.out.println("Area to be Painted: " + SA + " square meters");
```

Comment: The variables `walls` and `width` are confined to scope within your `if` blocks. Move them to a higher scope and give them default initial values.

Comment: If `in.hasNextDouble()` is false, what do you believe the value of `width` is when you calculate `SA`, and why do you believe that?

Comment: They're declared inside `if` blocks, and they're not visible outside those blocks. If you declare them outside, they will be visible outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has what is known as [block scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Any variable declared within a block `{}` is not accessible outside the block. You can use variables from outside the scope, but not the other way. What you need to do is declare the variable outside the scope. You probably also want to throw an exception to the user.

```
double width;
if(in.hasNextDouble()){
    width = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Width/Height: " + width);
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter only numbers");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Im new to programming and was not aware

Answer (score 0):

You declared `width` inside the block of this `if` statement:

```
if(in.hasNextDouble()){
    double width = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Width/Height: " + width);
}
```

So this block is the scope of `width` and it's not *visible* outside of it. 
What you should do? 
Declare it like this:

```
double width;
if(in.hasNextDouble()){
    width = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Width/Height: " + width);
}
```

Now `width` will be *visible* to the rest of `main()` although it may be uninitialized. So maybe this is safer:

```
double width = 0.0;
```